# Implement 'loading' icon while waiting for server response (AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs, response, loading, wait, angular-ng-if

I am pulling data from an API, so that a template is populated with the response values. However, it sometimes takes around 6 seconds to successfully pull the data, at which point the template is blank except for the headings.

### Loading...

Position:
Age:
Height:
Club:

### Loading finished:

Anthony Lopes
Portugal
Position: Goalkeeper
Age: 26
Height: 184 cm
Club: Olympique Lyonnais

I want to apply a loading icon (a spinny wheel or something) to indicate that it is waiting for a response from the API.

I'm assuming I need to set the loading state and attach it to a variable, and then say `ng-if="loadingContent()"` or something, and then create a function to show the loading state.

Is that right? If so can flesh out the process a bit more for me?

If not, how do you do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the cgbusy directive:
https://github.com/cgross/angular-busy

Include the file in your HTML and add cgBusy as dependency to your app:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['cgBusy']);
```

You can setup a loading template and include it in your HTML like this:

```
<div cg-busy="{promise: myPromise.$promise, message: 'Loading...',backdrop:true}"></div>
```

You now have to bind $scope.myPromise to your API call (which should return a promise) like:

```
$scope.myPromise = $http.post("/echo/json/", data).success(function(data, status) {
        $scope.hello = data;
    });
```

This way the loading template (which you can edit) will be visibile as long as the API call is busy. You can add this to any API call you want or add an other template for other calls.

You can customize everything easy in the directive, read more on the provided Github page.

Answer (score 0):

Simply just assign a boolean scope variable when your AJAX/HTTP call is completed. In my example, I just use a `$timeout` of 5 seconds.

**JS/Angular:**

```
$scope.isLoaded = false;
    $timeout(function() {
        $scope.isLoaded = true;
    }, 5000)
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<!-- This element is displayed while loading -->
<div ng-if="!isLoaded" id="loading-container">
    <div id="loading-inner">
        <img src="http://loadinggif.com/images/image-selection/27.gif" />
    </div>

    <h4>Loading...</h4>
    Position: <br/>
    Age: <br/>
    Height: <br/>
    Club:<br/>
</div>

<!-- This element is displayed after loading is complete -->
<div ng-if="isLoaded">
    <h4> Loading finished:</h4>
    Anthony Lopes<br/>
    Portugal<br/>
    Position: Goalkeeper<br/>
    Age: 26<br/>
    Height: 184 cm<br/>
    Club: Olympique Lyonnais<br/>
</div>
```

Honestly, I could spend hours styling the loading screen in the demo, but that's decent enough to get you on your way so that you can understand how it all works.

If you are using Angular's `$http` function to perform your API calls, you would set the variable like so:

```
$scope.isLoaded = false;

$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/someUrl'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    $scope.isLoaded = true;
});
```

**[WORKING EXAMPLE](http://codepen.io/zilions/pen/JXqeNp)**

Comment: But when the call takes 3 or 6 seconds (depending on connection) it will always stay for 5 seconds which is a pity, right?

Comment: @JasonvanderZeeuw - As I stated, I only used `$timeout` as an example. You need to set the scope variable as `true` within your AJAX/HTTP promise. Are you using Angular's `$http` function to perform your API calls?

Comment: I get your point. I use the cgBusy directive as mentioned in my comment, but this is also a way indeed. But with this variable you would have to make a success/error to remove the loader with every possible response, right?

Comment: Depends how many `$http` calls your website has. You could just create a `service` and inject it as an `interceptor` within your `config` to broadcast an event. There are many ways this can be done, yet it all depends on the structure of the application and how many API calls it has.

Answer (score 0):

Below approach you can use:

Template Code:

```
<div>
    <div ng-if="isLoading" class="loaderIcon">
    </div>

    <div ng-if="!isLoading">
        <div>
            Main Content
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Contorller Code:

```
app.controller('mainCntrl', function($scope, backendService) {

    function successCallback(res) {
        $scope.isLoading = false;
    }

    function failureCallback(res) {
        $scope.isLoading = false;
    }

    $scope.fetchData = function() {
        $scope.isLoading = true;
        backendService.fetchData(successCallback, failureCallback);
    }

});
```

Service Code:

```
app.service('backendService', function($http) {
    this.fetchData = function(successCallback, failureCallback) {
        $http.put('url', data).then(function(res) {
            successCallback(res);   
        }, function(res) {
            failureCallback(res);
        });
    };

});
```

Comment: This could fail with multiple calls, when the first is ready, the loader will immediately hide. But would work fine for one call with a loader!